# How to copy data in a folder into internal folder Android?

Tags: android, json

I'm developing an Android application, I have to implement a function that update the files in a certain folder.

In my Android Studio project I have created a folder named "raw" in /res/raw that contais some JSON file.

When my app is started a folder is created :

```
  /* Creation of local folder with JSON inside */
  File JSONStorage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MYFOLDER");
  if (!JSONStorage.exists()) {
   if (!JSONStorage.mkdirs()) {
    Log.d("App", "failed to create directory");
   }
  }
```

Now I want copy the content of res/raw/ in MYFOLDER, that is in the device.

How i can do this ? Is it possible copy all file in the second folder without know the name of all file ?

I need a function that copy all file in raw folder in MYFOLDER automatically.

Comment: Step #1: Call `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.whatever_you_called_it)` on some `Context`, like your `Activity`, to get an `InputStream` on the raw resource. Replace `whatever_you_called_it` with the base name of the file that you placed in `res/raw/`, without the `.json` extension. Step #2: Open a `FileOutputStream` where you want the file to go. Step #3: Use Java I/O to read from the `InputStream` and write to the `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: Is it a good practices copy this data in a custom folder or is it better copy in assets folder ?

Comment: You cannot write to assets. Assets are very similar to raw resources; they are input to your app, not a destination for output.

Comment: No wait, I need to copy the file contained in RAW to MYFOLDER that is a internal folder.

Comment: That is what my comment describes how to do. If you prefer, you can store your JSON as an asset, then use `getAssets().open()` instead of `getResources().openRawResource()`.